# How Spring MVC getting data from Model and why is modelAttribute object created everytime after submitting form?

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, spring-mvc

Everytime I submit form with errors processForm() method is called, errors are checked, BindingResult hasErrors() is true and I return customer-form which have error message next to wrong inputs, but before all that new Customer is always created and setters are called. Why Spring creating new Customer object everytime I submit form and how long Spring keep customer data ? Also, why my form inputs become empty if I mark url in browser and hit enter ?

I have form:

```
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">
    First name: <form:input path="firstName" />
    <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" />
    <br><br>
    Last name (*): <form:input path="lastName" />
    <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" />
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

and Controllers:

```
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel) {
        theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "customer-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(
            @ModelAttribute("customer") @Valid Customer theCustomer,
            BindingResult theBindingResult) {
       if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) return "customer-form";
        return "customer-confirmation";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Why Spring creating new Customer object everytime I submit form and how long Spring keep customer data ?**

Generally speaking, Spring is not creating new `Customer` object every time you submit the form. It is binding form data to the model object that you sent from the `GET` handler:

```
theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
```

And in the `POST` handler, the same object is being resolved with

```
@ModelAttribute("customer") @Valid Customer theCustomer,
```

See how this resolution is done with [`@ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) in Spring Framework Documentation.

The data will normally live through the requests if not configured otherwise, for example with [`@SessionAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-sessionattributes).

> **Also, why my form inputs become empty if I mark url in browser and hit
>   enter ?**

This is a new `GET` request, ie, it's all the same as the first time you enter the URL and press enter!